# What is the correct calculation here?

Tags: arithmetic, average

I bought some books as below

[image]

I want to consolidate these expenses together like this

[image]

**Method 1**

```
Purchase Rate in Table2 = AVERAGE(37.44+22.97+23.02) = 27.81
Quantity in Table2 = 50
Therefore Amount total in Table2 = 27.81*50 = 1390.5
But from Table1, Amount total is only 1236.37
```

**Method 2**

```
Amount total from Table1 = 1236.37
Quantity in Table2 = 50
Therefore, Purchase Rate in Table2 = 1236.27/50 = 24.7274
But average Purchase Rate from Table1 = AVERAGE(37.44+22.97+23.02) = 27.81
```

Which method is correct here? Feels like a simple calculation, but I'm definitely missing something here.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to calculate? The average price of a book? The average price of $50$ books? Or the total price of the $50$ books that you bought?

Comment: @an4s Average price of 50 books and Total price of 50 books

Comment: cf: [weighted average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Mathematical_definition)

Comment: The total price of the $50$ books is simply the sum of the last column. The average price is then given by the ratio of the total price to the total number of books.

Comment: @an4s - Ok, so you are saying that the Method2 is the right calculation, which gives me the average price as 24.7274. Then, shouldn't that be equal to the average price from Table1 (which is 27.81) ?

Comment: Well, think it out.  Method one you average the price of each *type* of object but you make no effort to take into account how many of the type you bought.  $738$ diamond rings for $20,000$ dollars each ... and a pack of gum for $98$ cents. what does it matter that the average price of a pack of gum and *one* diamond ring is $10,000.49$ if you bought $738$ diamond rings?  Method 1 is useless garbage.  Method 2 you take the total you spent and divide it by the number of things you bought.  Thats what average means, isn't it.  So method 2 is useful and method 1 is not.

Comment: "Then, shouldn't that be equal to the average price from Table1 (which is 27.81) ?"  What good does it do to know what the average *type* of book costs when you don't buy the same number of each type.  If you bought one cheap book and five million expensive books then considering the cheap book and expensive book as being equally important is dishonest.

Comment: @fleablood - Makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your second answer is correct. You have to consider not just the base price, but how much is being bought.

For example, say you have a lottery and you have a 1% chance of getting \$0 and a 99% chance of getting \$10. Is the average going to be \$5? Of course not; it will be almost \$10. Averages between one individual thing and another can be calculated using the simple $\frac{a+b}{2}$ formula, but when multiple instances of the same thing occur, that's when things get complicated.

This is also the basis for *expected value*. Take a Google search to learn more! In essence, expected value is just arithmetic means, but with much more factors in it.

-FruDe